# I want to make a checkbox. A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, checkbox, submit

I want to make a checkbox. This is an error that I get when running my code:

```
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'datagejala.dart';

class Diagnosis2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Diagnosis2State createState() => _Diagnosis2State();
}

class _Diagnosis2State extends State<Diagnosis2> {
  //initState
  bool selected = false;
  var userStatus = List<bool>();

  Future<List<DataGejala>> getContactsFromJSON(BuildContext context) async{
    String jsonString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data/penyakit.json");
    List<dynamic> raw = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    return raw.map((f) => DataGejala.fromJSON(f)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select City'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getContactsFromJSON(context),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].g_nama),
                    trailing: Checkbox(
                        value: userStatus[index],
                        onChanged: (bool val) {
                          setState(() {
                            userStatus[index] = !userStatus[index];
                          });
                        }),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the value you tried to use for the Text widget is null therefore your error is not anything to do with the checkbox but rather that you need to reexamine why "snapshot.data[index].g_nama" is returning null and not with a string as you would like for it to be.